# Python : Getting a TypeError when working with Tweepy dictionaries

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to capture media urls from people's tweets using Tweepy in python.

```
tweet_media = clean_data['entities']['media']['media_url']
```

tweet_media is supposed to be the direct url to the media from a tweet, but I keep getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
    tweet_media = clean_data['entities']['media']['media_url']
```

Clean_data is where all the tweet data is stored during the stream.

It was my understanding that under entities and media, there was media_url, so what's going on here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Without knowing `clean_data`, from the error it looks like at some point it is no longer a dictionary but a list. Have you tried looking at it step by step? I.e. First look at `clean_data['entities']`, if it is still a dictionary look at `clean_data['entities']['media']` and so on

Comment: oh, sorry - clean_data is where all the incoming tweet data is stored

Comment: As @Stefan said, probably either `clean_data['entities']` or `clean_data['entities']['media']` are a list, not dictionary - please print debug / evaluate them. (We don't know the `clean_data` content to answer)

Comment: @Stefan I have had a look at my own ```clean_data``` and also at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object and ```'media_url'``` should be there. Maybe I need to group it in with ```'media'```?

Comment: @AvivYaniv I can print ```clean_data``` and show you what I mean

Comment: @pigeonburger Yes please

Comment: @AvivYaniv Ok I have updated it

Comment: `media` is a list of dicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see your data `clean_data['entities']['media']` is a list, so you need to access its 1st element and then get its `media_url`

```py
tweet_media = clean_data['entities']['media'][0]['media_url']
print(tweet_media)
>>> 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EgaJqy0U8AAlL7B.jpg'
```

Comment: Ohhhh right so to get the url I want I just add ```[0]```?

Comment: yes but that will only get 1st media's url, if there are more media the you can use a for loop to iterate over `clean_data['entities']['media']` and print each url